Select ONLY records from table using group by and condition
I have a table with the following columns and rows



Name
Location
AppID
CreatedBy




abc
US
123
Auto


abc
US
123
Manual


abc
US
456
Auto


abc
US
456
Auto


abc
US
789
Manual


abc
US
789
Auto


abc
US
1234
Auto


abc
US
1234
Auto



I would like to get records that have duplicate App IDs (more than 1 record) and created by "Auto", like this:



Name
AppID
CreatedBy




abc
456
Auto


abc
456
Auto


abc
1234
Auto


abc
1234
Auto



I have the following query, but it doesn't return the expected output:
select name, appId, createdby 
from <table> 
where appId in (
    select appId from <table> 
    group by appId 
    having count(*) > 1
) and createdby ='Auto' 
order by appId desc;

How can I fix this?

Try putting the where created by = auto in the subquery (with the group by)?

@Barmar, because one record was created by Manual. The condition is, it should return only records that are created by Auto and there should be two records with the same appId

But the subquery counts all the records, not just the records created by Auto.

The easiest way I know to get downvoted is to ask people not to use downvotes.

Also: what version of MySQL? 8.0 and later may be able to use a windowing function to do this more efficiently.

Noted @JoelCoehoorn, thank you

@JoelCoehoorn, apologies - this is a oracle DB, but not mysql. I have updated it as mysql incorrectly by mistake.

"but it doesn't return the expected output".  Your requirement is "... and created by Auto", but your query doesn't have that condition.  Of course it won't return the expected output.

Note that tables have rows, not records.

Does the Name column never have any other value than abc? Does it matter in this case?

You are almost there with your query, you just need to add a filter to the sub-query WHERE  createdby ='Auto' so that you are only counting the Auto rows for duplicates.
SELECT name, appId, createdby 
FROM   table_name
WHERE  appId IN (
         SELECT appId
         FROM   table_name
         WHERE  createdby ='Auto' 
         GROUP BY appId 
         HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
       )
AND    createdby ='Auto' 
ORDER BY appId DESC;

Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE table_name (Name, Location, AppID, CreatedBy) AS
SELECT 'abc', 'US',  123, 'Auto'   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'abc', 'US',  123, 'Manual' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'abc', 'US',  456, 'Auto'   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'abc', 'US',  456, 'Auto'   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'abc', 'US',  789, 'Manual' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'abc', 'US',  789, 'Auto'   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'abc', 'US', 1234, 'Auto'   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'abc', 'US', 1234, 'Auto'   FROM DUAL;

Outputs:



NAME
APPID
CREATEDBY




abc
1234
Auto


abc
1234
Auto


abc
456
Auto


abc
456
Auto




If you want groups where they rows are all Auto and there are duplicate rows then:
SELECT name, appId, createdby 
FROM   table_name
WHERE  appId IN (
         SELECT appId
         FROM   table_name
         WHERE  createdby ='Auto' 
         GROUP BY appId 
         HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN createdBy =  'Auto' THEN 1 END) > 1
         AND    COUNT(CASE WHEN createdBy != 'Auto' THEN 1 END) = 0
       )
ORDER BY appId DESC;

Which gives the same output for your sample data.
fiddle

Try this:
WITH counts AS (
    select Name, Location, AppID, CreatedBy
       , count(*) over (partition by AppId) as AutoCount
    from <table>
    where CreatedBy = 'Auto'
)
SELECT Name, Location, AppID, CreatedBy
FROM counts
WHERE AutoCount > 1
ORDER BY AppID DESC

See it work here:

https://dbfiddle.uk/8KHaZyvZ


Thanks, Joel. When I try to run it on the database, it throws an exception as "Autocount" invalid identifier

@Syed: Then you did something wrong. As you see in the query (line #3) the count column is properly called AutoCount and accessed with the same name in line #9. And the liked dbfiddle shows that this query is correct. You must have made some mistake.

Hello Another solution using the exists operator:
select name, location , appid
from your_table t
where createdby='auto'
and exists (
select * from your_table 
where appid=t.appid
group by createdby
having count(*)>1
);

Hope it helps.

select x.AppID,t.Name,t.CreatedBy from
(
  select t.AppID
  from your_table as t
  group by t.AppID
  having min(CreatedBy)=max(CreatedBy)and min(CreatedBy)='Auto'
)x
join your_table t on x.AppID=t.AppID

please have a look if it is suitable for you

This will return records that don't have any duplicates and the one row has CreatedBy=Auto.

It happens to work with the example data because all appId's are duplicated.
